# Neo4j: lock store

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm developing a project which is based on Spring Data Neo4j using the repositories approach. The issue is that I can't read and write the graph at the same time (which is required in my app), since I get this error otherwise. My Neo4j server instance is not running but I have different processes which are trying to work with the database (i.e.: the same application context is loaded in different main methods and here should be probably the problem, I don't know). I am used to relational databases and hardly understand this behaviour. Which would be the best approach to get rid of this issue? Or, is it actually possible?

This is part of my application context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
          xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
          xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd">

          <!-- Neo4j -->
          <neo4j:config storeDirectory="/data/production/graph.db"/>
          <neo4j:repositories base-package="org.domain.project.repositories.neo4j"/>
```

With this context, I'm able to access the neo4jOperations interface in my custom neo4j repository implementation and to build queries without problems. On the other hand, the current user has privileges to access the data folder, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write from two proceses to the same Neo4j database. Instead, you should set up a Neo4j HA cluster, and use one of the cluster instances as the embedded database for SDN. Replication etc will then be transparent to your applications. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/neo4j/6mxSvhemd8M for details.

Comment: Would be using the REST API (server instance running somewhere reachable) another option?

Comment: @Turquesa Yes, it would allow multiple clients to write, however there are certain things you give up when using the REST api, such as your ability to manage transactions.

Comment: Ok, then this is not a valid solution for me since at some point I need to work with the Neo4j Java API itself to do massive inserts and I'm managing transactions (the save method from the repository introduces a huge overhead). Thanks for your comments.